# ng-init trigger a function at end of angularjs controller

Tags: php, angularjs, parameter-passing, onload, ng-init

I want to pass user name and id  from php login page to angularjs controller onload . i tried it  by ng-init to call basicDetails(username, id)  . this function trigger at end of main controller. and also another problem passed parameter to angularjs variable print passed value in inside basicDetails function , outside it shows value as empty

```
<body  ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="basicDetails('<?php echo$_SESSION["username"];?> ','<?php echo$_SESSION["itmsNo"];?> ')">
<center>
    <div >
      <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b><br>
                <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset  Password</a><br>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out</a>
    </div>   </center>
<!-- Main div showing different templates loaded by ng-view directive -->
<div class="container main"  ng-view>
</div>
```

Maincontroller.js

```
templeApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http','webService', function($scope,$rootScope, $http,webService,user) {
    $rootScope.loggedUser;
    $scope.itmsNo;

    // This function trigger by ng-init , but called end of main controller 
    $scope.basicDetails = function(logedUser,itmsNo){
        $rootScope.loggedUser =logedUser;
        $scope.itmsNo =itmsNo;    
        console.log($scope.loggedUser );  // console print actual value          
    }
    console.log('..'+$scope.loggedUser );  // console print empty value

    $scope.user = webService.userData('impl/userData.php',$scope.loggedUser);

}]);
```

Comment: i tried hidden filed, but not working .why?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, `ng-init` runs after the rest of the controller code.  This is why you get `undefined` when you try to log it outside of `basicDetails`.  It hasn't been set yet because `basicDetails` sets it later.

So run all of your initialization code inside of `basicDetails`:

```js
templeApp.controller('mainController'...
  $scope.basicDetails = function(logedUser, itmsNo) {
    $rootScope.loggedUser;
    $scope.itmsNo;

    $rootScope.loggedUser = logedUser;
    $scope.itmsNo = itmsNo;
    console.log($scope.loggedUser);

    $scope.user = webService.userData('impl/userData.php', $scope.loggedUser);    
  }
}}
```

You can rename it from `basicDetails` to something like `init` so it makes more sense.

Comment: its working.but my all of my code is inside function is it good practice?

Comment: I tried hidden filed, but not working .Why two way binding not working?

Comment: It's all part of initialization, so yes it's the *only* practice if you want to pass it in through `ng-init`.  If you have other controller code that doesn't depend on `logedUser` or `itemsNo` being set at compile time, it would go outside of the function.

Comment: I see no code with bindings or hidden input fields.  Sounds like it might be a separate question.